# When I from a navigation controller( which is embed in a TabbarController) push to a new TabbarController, there is short than normal

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

When I push from a navigation controller (which is embed in a tabbar controller) to a new tabbar controller.

There is an issue here, the new tabbar controller is short than normal.

You can see the black rectangle under the tabbar of new tabbar controller.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And in the view hierarchy:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How to solve this issue here?

If can not, how to avoid this issue? I want from a tabbar controller push to a new tabbar controller.

Comment: Hi, which viewController is pushing the view controller ? The Viewcontroller, the TabBarViewController or An navigationViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a storyboard item for TabBarController you wish to push to from navigation Controller, go to it and click on the checkbox  **Hide Bottom Bar On Push** . This will hide the bottom tabBar of the parent TabBarController.

Do note that Apple does not recommend TabBarController to be rootViewController of Navigation Controller.

[image]

Comment: why `Apple does not recommend TabBarController to be rootViewController of Navigation Controller.` ?